# create a pfx file from a .cer and a .pem file

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, pfx

I have used openssl to create a .key and .cer file in pem format (you can read them). Now I want to create .pfx file from them. I have read openssl doumentation it says something like following command I can use

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.cer -inkey privateKey.key -out certificate.pfx -certfile CACert.cer
```

but I don't know which one is my .cer file (certificate.cer or CACert.cer) what is differences between these two files?

Comment: Docs: https://info.ssl.com/how-to-create-a-pfx-p12-certificate-file-using-openssl/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `certificate.cer` is your public key and the `CACert.cer` file (as it names suggest) is the public key of a CA (maybe the one who has signed your certificate).

The `-in` switch specifies input certificate to embed in output file

The `-inkey` switch specifies the key file you've generated using OpenSSL

The `-out` switch tells the openssl your desired name for output file

The `-certfile` is used to specify additional certificates to add to the output pfx file (it could be ignored)

Comment: what if I have no CACert.cer or I have used Self Signed Certificate? does the command generate right .pfx file?

Comment: Yes. It's not necessary to have the issuer certificate in your pfx file. If you install such pfx (without CA cer) in your windows, you have to install its CA certificate independently to make it possible for windows to detect the certificate chain and validate the certificate

Comment: what if we dont have the private key ?

Comment: The pfx format is typically used as a container for a pair of public-private key. If you don't have a private key, then maybe a simple cer file, containing a public key, would be enough for your use case

Comment: When executing the command: openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificate.cer -inkey privateKey.key -out certificate.pfx -certfile CACert.cer

Return: Unable to load certificates.

But I am referencing the certificate in the executed command, inside the folder that is my .cer

Comment: Are you sure about the spelling of the file names and also the permission of them?