# Sign a file exe windows ¬ Convert .pem to pfx

Tags: powershell, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, digital-signature

I am trying to sign a .exe file and I have a certificate and private key in format .pem.

I convert my cert using openssl to format .pfx

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in "cert.pem" -inkey "key.pem" -out certificate.pfx -certfile "CA.cer"
```

I try using signtool

```
 signtool sign /f "certificate.pfx" /p mypass /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode "app.exe"
```

But I have the next error

```
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

Reference

[Signing .exe with .cer file (what is my certificate's name that signtool.exe is asking for?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879812/signing-exe-with-cer-file-what-is-my-certificates-name-that-signtool-exe-is)

Comment: Try running the command with  /debug flag to get more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946399/signtool-error-no-certificates-were-found-that-met-all-given-criteria-with-a-wi

Comment: Using debug option got. The following certificates were considered:
    Issued to: *.xx.xx
    Issued by: Thawte RSA CA 2018
    Expires:   Sat Sep 12 07:00:00 2020
    SHA1 hash: 607xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxBE8

After EKU filter, 0 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 0 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.

Comment: Right now, I am using the certs on my web server, Is posible use the same certificate for sign my app .exe