# Code Signing Certificate - Creating a PFX from a godaddy SPC & Key File

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, code-signing-certificate

Problem:

I generated a CRT using openssl; first I made a Key file; then Used the key file to generate a CRT.

I put the CRT text into the godaddy window; when they issued the code signing cert, they issued a SPC.

My Key and CRT are both TEXT, so I cannot import them through windows and standard utilities were unrecognized.

How do I create a PFX out of this? I cannot use internet explorer and windows sdks arent installing tools i need properly?

Comment: Related (but not a dup): [Create a pfx file from a .cer and a .pem file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19199293/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While many had success using visual studio toolkits, IE, etc, - all errored out for me. The best way to do this was to use the OPENSSL functions used to create the key & crt

1) Convert my KEY file (text) into a PVK file (binary)

```
openssl rsa -in EXAMPLE.key -outform PVK -pvk-strong -out EXAMPLE.pvk
```

2) Download PVK Import utility from microsoft (avoids Visual Studio packs, etc)

[Download Microsofts PVK Import Util Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6563)

3) Convert using the newly made PVK file (above) and the GoDaddy issued SPC

```
pvkimprt -PFX EXAMPLE.spc EXAMPLE.pvk
```

Source: [PvkImport Instructions Walkthrough](http://pad.asp-software.org/spec/howto_pvkimprt.php)

Note, you will need to use the proper directories. In this example, I put the EXE in the same folder as my CRT, KEY, PVK, SPC files.